# React + Alt: Use data from multiple stores to make a request to DataSource

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux, alt.js, react-alt

I am working on an app using React with Alt flux implementation.
Currently, I'm trying to figure out the best way to use data from multiple Alt stores to compose a request to the backend.

Say, I have a `SheetDataStore`, `FiltersStore` and a `fetchFilteredData` method in my `DataSource` file. To get proper data from backend, i need to pass to `fetchFilteredData` both some sheet data and filters, but when you call the `fetchFilteredData` method from one of the stores, you can pass some arguments and the state of just that exact store.

So i see 2 ways of handling this case:

1) I make 2 actions: `prepareFilters` and `fetchData`. The `prepareFilters` is called from a component and gets handled by `FilterStore`, which prepares all required data and after that calls `fetchData` action, passing the prepared data as an argument. The `SheetDataStore` handles the `fetchData` action and calls the `fetchFilteredData` having all required data now.

What i don't like here is that it seems to me, Stores should not be calling actions, so that's kind of a hacky solution.

2) I import `FilterStore` to the `SheetDataStore` and use `FilterStore.getState()` inside of one of `SheetDataStore` methods to get all the data i need. That seems easy, but there might be some pitfalls of coupling the stores like that.

Are there any best practices for such a case? Maybe some of you faced similar issue and can recommend which of the paths to take from your experience?

Answer (score 1):

Do the binding in the component. Say you have `FilterComponent` then pass the search action `SheetDataAction.search` to it:
`<FilterComponent search={SheetDataAction.search} />`

And in the `FilterComponent.render()` do something like `<button onClick={() => this.props.search(this.props.criteria)} />`

Comment: Fair point, but in this case, you'll need to have all the data available in the component, which i don't have. In short, i decided to go with the second option i mentioned in my question and it's working for me.